# Off-topic close on popular question

Tags: discussion, closed-questions

The SO question, [XPath and XSLT 2.0 for .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525299/xpath-and-xslt-2-0-for-net) was closed by casperOne as being off-topic, yet the question itself has had over 17k views and 50 upvotes, and the first answer has 83 upvotes. How can a question this popular be off-topic (especially since it seems to meet SO question criteria)? It's obviously of interest to the community.

Now that the question is closed, there is no opportunity to update answers as new information becomes available...

Comment: You can still update/edit existing/outdated answers on closed questions.

Comment: What I meant is this. It is a SO policy (bad or good) that gives some people supreme powers. These people can do anything and when they do it, the possibility of what they have done, gets undone is zero.

Comment: @SNash It takes 5 users to vote to reopen a question, even by a mod.  That actually happens fairly often, certainly not never.  You'll also see a mod reverse their (or another mod's) action based on a meta post at least every few days.  Sorry, try again.

Comment: @Can you provide a real example of a mod reverse this? My guess: you can't!

Comment: @SNash I can't provide an example of a mod reversing the closure of *this* question, no, because this question has never been reopened.  I can provide examples of a mod reopening a question that they closed, or that was closed by another mod, same same for deletion.  As I said, it happens reasonably regularly (often as a result of an edit, but not always).

Comment: @snash Just check out a couple of my answers here for examples.

Comment: Unlike some Q&A sites, StackExchange maintain quality by curating questions and being strict about what is kept on the site. Some other sites may try to do that by putting up a paywall, for example.

Comment: I guess things just aren't the same as when Jeff Atwood wrote his moderation blog in 2009 http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/a-theory-of-moderation/. Funny how this question was closed three years after it was asked... I guess my perspective is now obsolete too.

Answer (score 21):

Popular != on topic.

And as it stands, what we considered on topic in 2009 and what we consider on topic in 2013 are **very** different things.

---

The question itself is asking for speculation on whether certain technologies would or not be included in a set of libraries, something even the creators/maintainers of those libraries cannot conclusively answer.

It is not answerable. Hence, off-topic.

The yardstick should be - if asked today, what would happen to it? It would get closed rather quickly.

Comment: +1 Have you been waiting for this question? Answered in just one minute … :)

Comment: @insertusernamehere - Comes up often enough that I don't really need to think too much about it ;)

Comment: I certainly understand that popularity does not always equal on topic, but being an active user of StackExchange, I get frustrated at times with our rigidity to rule enforcement. Since this is a user-driven community, shouldn't there be more latitude in allowing questions that others consider useful, even if they don't meet on-topic requirements in the strictest sense? While I understand that the original question is poorly worded, the question and its resulting answers are obviously being used by SO users.

Comment: Yeah!  Mob rule!

Comment: @newmanth - The reason StackExchange sites are as useful to their users as they are is the rigidity with which we enforce these rules. If we simply allow the community to decide, we would end up with a site full of lol-cats and other **popular** content. The line has to be drawn somewhere.

Comment: @newmanth: Closed != Deleted. It's still available to people who might be looking for that information.

Comment: @newmanth There are thousands of forums q/a sites, etc. on programming realistic topics for which you can ask these types of questions.  Everything doesn't need to have a place on SE.